# ggplot2 facet_wrap() is not displaying all the available data

Tags: r

Reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(haven)
library(dplyr)

data <- read_dta('http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/s7zqb2e0avyp1gk/nswd_old_12.dta')
data$treatedOrNonSample <- ifelse(data$sample == 1, 0, ifelse(data$treat == 1, 1, 2))
treatOrCPS <- subset(data, data$treatedOrNonSample!=2)

m_ps <- glm(treat ~ age + age2 + ed + hisp + married + nodeg + re74 + re75 + black, 
                    family=binomial(link="probit"), data=treatOrCPS)

prs_df <- data.frame(pr_score = predict(m_ps, type = "response"),
                         treated = m_ps$model$treat)

labs <- paste("Status:", c("Treated", "CPS Sample"))

prs_df %>%
   mutate(treated = ifelse(treated == 1, labs[1], labs[2])) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = pr_score)) +
   geom_histogram(color = "white") +
   facet_wrap(~treated) +
   xlab("Probability of being in Treatment Condition") +
   theme_bw()
```

I get the following:

[image]

Why is there no data available for the right-most condition?  I'm losing my mind on this seemingly trivial topic, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you examine your resultant data before plotting it? Since you aren't getting ggplot2 errors, you prbly shld do that before making assumptions that the "error" is with ggplot2.

Comment: I did.  When I subset the data by treatment status and plot, I get these graphs: https://i.imgur.com/H0xAare.png.  I am running the following commands: https://i.imgur.com/DlXAFpB.png

Comment: Yes, yes you did. But, did you look at the Y axis on both of those? You might want to actually read the docs on the parameters to `facet_wrap()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `color=white` makes the data visible:

```
prs_df %>%
    mutate(treated = ifelse(treated == 1, labs[1], labs[2])) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = pr_score)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    facet_wrap(~treated) +
    xlab("Probability of being in Treatment Condition") +
    theme_bw()
```

However, because the counts in the 'CPS sample' group are way higher, the data in the 'treated' group is still barely visible.